# Brushing teeth before or after breakfast

Tags: dentistry, hygiene, oral-health

Usually in the morning I brush my teeth after breakfast. But my dentist told me that it's better not brush them right after eating food, because eating makes them soft.

So now I brush my teeth before breakfast. Is this the correct procedure?

PS. Just found [this article](http://www.mertondental.co.uk/blog/when-should-i-brush-my-teeth-before-or-after-breakfast/), the author has the same opinion.

Just want to get a additional confirmation.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes. The acid in the food can harm the enamel and brushing it to soon can remove it. So wait at least 30 minutes, brush before or avoid acidy foods.

Brushing abrasion of softened and remineralised dentin: an in situ study
T Attin et al. Caries Res. Jan-Feb 2004 [[Source]](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/14684979/):

> It is concluded that for protection of dentin surfaces at least 30 min should elapse before toothbrushing after an erosive attack.

[Mayo Clinic:](http://www.mayoclinic.org/healthy-lifestyle/adult-health/expert-answers/brushing-your-teeth/faq-20058193)

> If you've eaten an acidic food or drink, avoid brushing your teeth for
> at least 30 minutes. These acids weaken tooth enamel, and brushing too
> soon can remove enamel. If you know you're going to eat or drink
> something acidic, brush your teeth beforehand.

[Colgate.com](http://www.colgate.com/en/us/oc/oral-health/basics/brushing-and-flossing/article/is-brushing-teeth-after-eating-good-for-you-0313):

- Acidy foods: oranges, lemons, and grapefruit
- Drinking water after you eat the acidy foods helps easy it away

Also, brushing before eating can remove a lot of bacterial buildup, before you start eating again.

Comment: The Mayo Clinic link doesn't get any reference on whether it's preferable to brush one's teeth before rather than 30-60 minutes after breakfast if one eats an acidic food or drink. https://www.healthshare.com.au/questions/45745-is-it-better-to-brush-teeth-before-or-after-breakfast-in-the-morning/ seems to indicate some disagreement between dentists. It'd be nice to have some scientific evidence.